# CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found

Tags: android, ionic-framework

so I try to use android emulator for my ionic apps since I need to try out sqlite which isn't possible with their web server approach.

Anyway. What I do:

cd myProject

ionic cordova build android => successful

ionic cardova    emulate android

```
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    /home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
[17:34:24]  lint finished in 3.58 s 
(node:1425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /opt/android-sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /opt/android-sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

    at /home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:288:29
    at _fulfilled (/home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/foo/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
(node:1425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1425) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Also:

```
$ avdmanager list avd
Parsing /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/patcher/v4/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-26/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-27/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/sources/android-27/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/package.xmlParsing /opt/android-sdk/tools/package.xmlAvailable Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: test
  Device: Nexus 4 (Google)
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/test.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
  Sdcard: 100M
---------
    Name: test123
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/test123.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
---------
    Name: test2
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/test2.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
---------
    Name: test3
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/test3.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
---------
    Name: thename
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/thename.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
---------
    Name: thename2
    Path: /home/foo/.android/avd/thename2.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
```

**so I do have avds - no?**

**Whats the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a path mismatch. Try specifying the avd explicitly

Comment: "Where" would that path mismatch be? Going to try it.

Comment: Ionic is saying to build an avd here -> /opt/android-sdk/tools/android sdk , your avdmanager list avd says /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/. I'd also launch the emulator directly to make sure the image works

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same error with:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

and run the Android Emulator (from terminal or Android Studio) and THEN use ionic cordova emulate android